# Counting number of days per year in a pandas dataframe of hourly data when value exceeds a threshold at least once in 24 hour day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, counting

I have a dataframe (df2) with 24 hourly data `[datetime (yy/mm/dd HH:MM)]` and `[obs (float)]` from 1929 through 2016.

Sample:

```
datetime          obs
1/1/1929 0:00   -0.051
1/1/1929 1:00   0.285
1/1/1929 2:00   0.62
1/1/1929 3:00   0.955
1/1/1929 4:00   1.138
1/1/1929 5:00   1.23
1/1/1929 6:00   1.169
1/1/1929 7:00   0.925
1/1/1929 8:00   0.62
1/1/1929 9:00   0.285
1/1/1929 10:00  0.01
1/1/1929 11:00  -0.142
1/1/1929 12:00  -0.081
1/1/1929 13:00  0.193
1/1/1929 14:00  0.559
1/1/1929 15:00  0.955
1/1/1929 16:00  1.26
1/1/1929 17:00  1.352
1/1/1929 18:00  1.321
1/1/1929 19:00  1.108
1/1/1929 20:00  0.742
1/1/1929 21:00  0.376
1/1/1929 22:00  0.071
1/1/1929 23:00  -0.111
1/2/1929 0:00   -0.142
...
12/31 2016 23:00  1.02
```

I want to determine how many days for each year in the dataframe that the `obs value` >= some threshold, e.g., >=1.0.  That is, if the `obs value >= 1.0` in any of the 24 records (hours) of a day, the count for that `day=1` or true.  I then want to count up the number of days per year when the `count=1` or true and get a new dataframe:

```
year  days
1929   5
1930   2
...
2016   10
```

I'm new to Python and just trying code I find via Google.

```
daysperyr = df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Y'))['obs'].count().to_frame().reset_index()
```

This just gives number obs per year

```
0  1929-12-31  8760
1  1930-12-31  8760
2  1931-12-31  8760
3  1932-12-31  8784
4  1933-12-31  8760
```

Comment: Am getting closer.  Tried:  daysperyr = df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Y'))['obs'].apply(lambda x: x[x >= threshold].count()).to_frame().reset_index()   Yielded:  1927-12-31    0
6  1928-12-31    1
7  1929-12-31    0
8  1930-12-31    0
9  1931-12-31    0
10 1932-12-31    0
11 1933-12-31    0
12 1934-12-31    4
13 1935-12-31    0
14 1936-12-31    0
15 1937-12-31    0
16 1938-12-31    0
17 1939-12-31    0
18 1940-12-31    1
19 1941-12-31    0
20 1942-12-31    0

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the number of days per year where at least one observation exceeds the threshold:

```
days = df[df['obs'] > threshold]['datetime'].dt.date.unique()
years = pd.to_datetime(days).to_series() \
            .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Y')) \
            .count()
```

If you want to strip the month and day from `years.index`:

```
years.index = years.index.year
```

Result (with random data):

```
1929    121
1930    116
1931    126
1932    109
1933    123
1934    122
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the number of observations per day that is above '0'(you can change 0 to whatever number)

```
df2 = df[df['obs']>0].groupby([df['datetime'].dt.year, df['datetime'].dt.date]).count().drop(columns = 'datetime')
```

Then we can use that to see how many days per year:

```
df2.groupby(level=0).size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it does not matter when during the day, or how many possible re-occurrences during the same day. You should aim for

```
treshold=1.0
(df2.obs.resample('D').max()>=treshold).resample('Y').sum()
```